# Create android TextView inside Fragment class by java code (without .xml)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**I'm working on class exercises which told me to:**

- Create a TextView inside a Fragment class named ForecastFragment.java and this fragment will be displayed in MainActivity.java.
- DO NOT use xml file, code it all by .java

**My work:**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        String text = "Thursday";
        textView.setText(text);

        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        return view;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ForecastFragment">

</FrameLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

- The TextView is not added and also the fragment => 100% Failed

**Problem:**

- In LinearLayout and TextView constructor, they require Context instance but we are in Fragment so "this" keyword die => I use getActivity() instead. Is this true or not?
- Why my code doesn't work.
- I still don't know how to constraint the TextView to parent.
- Use java to create elements is much harder than xml, so I need some source code to understand

Thank you everyone.

Comment: this is due to you're not adding you linearLayout into view that being returned. and as it's object of View class you can't add child try to use ViewGroup like LinearLayout or some other kind of view that extends ViewGroup as your parent instead of view.

Comment: U mean add fragment into a ViewGroup then add ViewGroup into MainActivity.

Comment: no no you got it totally wrong, can you share code of fragment_forecast.xml so i can explain it better.

Comment: Yes, I already add it above. hope u can help me solve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following thing occurred cause you are not adding your LinearLayout object to any parent which gonna be render on screen. as of now it is view object of View class which can't add subview.

**so make following changes:**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView textView = new TextView(view.getContext());
        String text = "Thursday";
        textView.setText(text);

        view.addView(linearLayout);    
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**now i will answer some of your questions:**
Problem:

- In LinearLayout and TextView constructor, they require Context
  instance but we are in Fragment so "this" keyword die => I use
  getActivity() instead. Is this true or not?

> it can work but if you try to use getActivity() while fragment is
> detached from activity it will return null so you have to check every
> time about that. so instead you can use viewObject.getContext() so it
> will be not null.

- Why my code doesn't work.

> as i explained earlier it;s working but you can't see it cause it
> not being attached to layout which is currently being shown.

- I still don't know how to constraint the TextView to parent. Use java & to create elements is much harder than xml, so I need some source code to understand

> for this you have to practice about each ViewGroup and how they
> manage child views. and also you can find many references online about
> them.

Comment: There is a problem, method addView() isn't exist.

Comment: have you changed the view object class with FrameLayout. cause FrameLayout has method addView and if possible provide updated code.

Comment: yes and view.addView() is still not exist

Comment: I think it should have addView because it extend ViewGroup class but some how my IDE raise an exception for that :)

Comment: Oh, thank you i fix it.